# Accessing Rails credentials from models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had the following working:

```
key = "\xD1\x9C\xAA\xFB/\xF3\xD7\x10\xAF\xBA\x97\x97\x00\xDA\xBF\xC1\xCE\xD6\xCB*\xCC\xF4w<2\xEA=o\x1EY\x16\xE5"
attr_encrypted :client_id, key: key
```

I then used this key for encrpytion.

I tried storing this same key in credentials both with and without quotes but it seems like i am unable to access them from the model

I tried:

```
  key_1 = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:encrypt, :xenon_a_1).to_s
  attr_encrypted :client_id, key: key_1
```

:

```
  key_1 = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:encrypt, :xenon_a_1)
  attr_encrypted :client_id, key: key_1.to_s
```

and without .to_s in both

I tried using .to_s with both of the following ways:

credentials:

```
encrypt:
  xenon_a_1: "\xD1\x9C\xAA\xFB/\xF3\xD7\x10\xAF\xBA\x97\x97\x00\xDA\xBF\xC1\xCE\xD6\xCB*\xCC\xF4w<2\xEA=o\x1EY\x16\xE5"
```

:

```
encrypt:
      xenon_a_1: \xD1\x9C\xAA\xFB/\xF3\xD7\x10\xAF\xBA\x97\x97\x00\xDA\xBF\xC1\xCE\xD6\xCB*\xCC\xF4w<2\xEA=o\x1EY\x16\xE5
```

I know my credentials is set up correctly because i am able to use AWS, PayPal, Stripe, and Braintree from it.

**I can only assume, is credentials not accessible from models?**

The error i receive when passing my form through is the same error i would get if my key was blank or not 32 bits.

Comment: What's the error that's occurring? Credentials are accessible throughout the entire stack where `Rails` is defined. Your issue is elsewhere. I'm not sure where but it is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it seems as if i am unable to turn a credentials variable into a string.  `.to_s` `"#{}"` aren't working.  On submit i am put'ing the credentials to the console but none of the options are adding quotation marks... not sure why.  Even if i store it as a string in credentials it won't work because it comes back in symbols and not letters/numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone coming across this and using attr-encrypted gem with ruby:

https://ankane.org/encryption-keys

This just saved me ^

Mentions my exact issue with a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model looks something like this:

```
class Foo
  key_1 = 'bar'
end
```

That won't work. That variable may as well not exist because you can't call it elsewhere in the class. For example:

```
class Foo
  key_1 = 'bar'

  def self.baz
    puts key_1
  end

  def baz
    puts key_1
  end
end
```

Test it with:

```
Foo.new.baz
NameError: undefined local variable or method `key_1' for #<Foo:0x00007fc720299570>
```

And:

```
Foo.baz
NameError: undefined local variable or method `key_1' for Foo:Class
```

Try looking for the variable and you won't find it:

```
Foo.instance_variables
=> []
Foo.class_variables
=> []
Foo.constants
=> []
```

You should instead instantiate it as a constant in the class:

```
class Foo
  KEY_1 = 'bar'

  def self.baz
    puts KEY_1
  end

  def baz
    puts KEY_1
  end
end
```

And test it:

```
Foo.baz
bar

Foo.new.baz
bar

Foo::KEY_1
=> "bar"
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  How come `key_1 = '/foo/'` from my example works but not when i attempt to use it with a credentials or `ENV['key_1']`  define?